# Easy way to convert from one type to another in java (when fields are similar)?

Tags: java, java-8

Lets say I have these two classes:

```
class A {
    String firstA;
    List<String> secondA;
}

class B {
   String firstB;
   List<String> secondB;
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert from A to B easily? Without having to do it manually for each field?

Comment: For what purpose do you need that?

Comment: No, there isn't. Define "similar". They may look "similar" to you but a computer doesn't understand the English language.

Comment: I just have two 3rd party libraries that return classes that have the same structure but are named differently. The class member variables are of the same type, just have different names.

Comment: In general there shouldn't be a need to this very often-- if your fields are often similar, make the similar types inherit from a common parent type.  If there is a legitimate need for something like this, something like the apache beanutils (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) might help

Comment: @DonCode For that purpose maybe in C++ but not Java. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: touche @akuzminykh

Comment: @DonCode You can use MapStruct. Check my answer below for more details

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

There is no native way in plain Java to convert an object of type A to an object of type B without having to copy the fields one by one.

---

### Longer answer

---

***Why is that?***

There is no such thing as **similar fields** in `Java`. The `Java` language by design does not support [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Thus said you cannot treat a two fields fields as **similar** / **same** by their names.

***How can I get it done?***

There are different approaches:

- **Manual mapping**

This is a boring but runtime performant approach.

- **`Inheritance` and `polymorphism`**

Not really a **mapping** approach, but rather treating the objects as **similar** by their common interface`and/or`parent class`.

- **Serialization** and **deserialization** to/from `String`

If the two types have fields with same names and types they can be mapped from one to another by serialization/deserialization (e.g. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)). This is not the best solution, but may do the good job in some rare cases.

- **Using `reflection` and `reflection`-based libraries**:

Reflection is another way of achieving the same goal, but with huge trade-offs. 
 This approach is not so different from the one above, but it allows to map fields with different names. Even though the approach is widely used (e.g. in [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html)) it is not very performant. The reflective operations may take significant time.

- **Using code generators**

There is another approach. As opposed to using reflection at runtime, the code generators (like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)) do the similar thing at compile time. Thus there is no runtime overhead as compared to manual mapping. Actually, the generated code looks quiet the same as the manually written one.

***How to choose one for my project?***

There is a bunch of different tools for mapping POJO types between each other.
Before choosing one of them for using in your project I'd suggest considering the following criteria:

- Is the particular case worth adding external dependency?
- Is it easy to read?
- Is it easy to modify the classes without breaking the code?
- Is it performant at runtime?
- etc...

***Subjective opinion:***

I personally like using MapStruct. It generates the methods for mapping at compile time, so there is no runtime reflective stuff causing overhead. You can map the objects at almost zero cost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think native java can do this.

There is a few libraries that would help you with this kind of problem.

I would recommend MapStruct : https://mapstruct.org/
I also used Orika and ModelMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You may use reflection for that purpose.

Look at java.lang.reflect, get the A.class and loop for every Field, to copy the values.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html

```
// warning: not tested nor compiled -take it as hint

A a = new A(); ...set values
B b = new B();
for (Field f : A.class.getFields()) {
    f.set(b,f.get(a);
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of what reflection is **not** for.

Comment: This is not a question about design, I agree that probably there are better strategies, but I have used reflection to dynamically copy certain objects (database records) into other objects (noSql documents) and the same class simply could not be used, the result was something very flexible, easy to maintain, that saved the project a lot of money, as the same code was reused to transform different types of entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelMapper a Java Library. http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: this works but is limited...for example when you have a List<Obj> then still need for loop.